# How to display specific product review form in cms page of magento 2.4.6?

Tags: magento2, review

We need to render the specific product review form on the CMS page for marketing purposes. Adding the below code into the CMS page but it's not helpful. Please suggest the solution.

```
{{block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" template="Magento_Review::form.phtml" product_id="1212"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Magento\Review\Block\Form` reads the product_id from request param `id`, instead of the way you are passing it.

**Magento\Review\Block\Form**

```php
/**
 * Get review product id
 *
 * @return int
 */
protected function getProductId()
{
    return $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
}
```

There are a few options you have. You can either add `?id= 1212` to the URL of your CMS page and use that, otherwise, I would suggest you write a custom block for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Custom Block to CMS Page:
Or Go to Content > Elements > Pages in the Magento admin panel and create a new CMS page (or edit an existing one where you want to display the review form).

```
{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\ProductReviewForm" template="Vendor_Module::form.phtml"}}
```

Create a Custom Block:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Review\Block\Form;

class ProductReviewForm extends Template
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getProductId()
    {
        // Get the dynamic product ID from the registry (or any other source)
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product')->getId();
    }

    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('review/product/post', ['id' => $this->getProductId()]);
    }
}
```

Create the Template File:
On this path app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<div>
    <form action="<?= $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
        <!-- Your review form fields here -->
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= $block->getProductId() ?>">
        <button type="submit">Submit Review</button>
    </form>
</div>
```